# What is the correct determiner with this expression?

Tags: determiners

I would like to know which structure is correct and why:

> A. **Differences of opinion** among political parties strengthen the health of democracies.

> B. **The differences of opinion** among political parties strengthen the health of democracies.

Some doubts:

- The statement is general (no prior  context) and not specific. **Rule #1** says that "the" must not be used in non-specific statements (we can not answer "which ones"?)
- According to **rule #2**, when an "x of y" structure is used, x becomes specific ("the x of y") and "the" must be used (as is also done with "the health of democracies")
- We all know that there are in all cases differences of opinion among all political parties in all democracies. According to **rule #3**, "the" must be used to convey the idea that there are differences in all cases (we can answer "which ones?": the differences of opinion that we know that exist, even though we can not specify them)

Comment: What makes you think that only one is correct? They're all perfectly grammatical, though they don't mean the same things.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It would be great if those different meanings could be explained. That's the point of the question!

Comment: *Differences of opinion among family members on whether to accept external investors are common.* https://www.ft.com/content/94213c84-fb9f-11e7-9bfc-052cbba03425

Comment: You refer to numbered "rules" as if they were well-known. What is the source of these particular formulations of rules of English usage?

Comment: What exactly are you up to? https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/332543/would-you-use-the-in-the-division-of-opinions/332609#332609  I already answered this question. Now, you are reposing my solution?? Generalities do not require the. A "the" would only be specific: The differences of opinion that existed in Brazil during blah blah. I vote to close this as it is already answered.

Comment: The differences of opinion among political parties (at that time) strengthened the health of democracies. Not a generality. It is specific. So, both are grammatical but they are not used the same way.

Answer (score 3):

My 2 cents (note that I am not a native speaker so I may be wrong):

1. Differences of opinion among political parties strengthen the health of democracies.

-> There may or may not be differences of opinion among parties. If there are differences, democracies are healthier.

2. The differences of opinion among political parties strengthen the health of democracies.

-> There are differences of opinion among parties. Always. These differences make democracies healthier. Even though "the" is used, it does not imply that the differences of opinion are identifiable and specific (as "the" usually implies). "The" only implies that the differences always exist. But, they cannot be identified (as this is a general statement that does not apply to any particular case of a democracy with identifiable differences).

Comment: It would be great if native speakers could corroborate your interesting speculative theory.

Comment: I am going to delete this answer. I *may* be wrong.

Comment: @rajesun - No need to delete.  Your answer is a valid observation.  Whether or not it answers the question is for us *voters* to decide.  The request for corroboration is just that, a request.  If your answer was not a valid observation, you would notice the downvotes.

Comment: It has never happened to me to hear or read of this sort of distinction between a noun with or without "the".

Comment: @rajesun: I think you're quite right. In the second example there might be identifiable differences of opinion, but there might not. In the general context the sentence suggests, the fine distinction you make between there definitely being differences of opinion and those differences being specifically identifiable is both well-expressed and observant of you. Upvoted.

Comment: I generally agree with this answer. I offer some clarifications in my recently posted answer, but I have upvoted this answer.

Comment: The use of the is **specific**: The differences of opinion that existed in the 1930's. VERSUS: Differences of opinion can be a good thing. **That is the difference between the two**. But the second one in the question cannot be construed as written as specific.

Answer (score 0):

Both sentences are correct, but they have their own contexts.  Without any foregoing context, the first sentence appears more correct, as it can stand on its own, alone.

Without the definite article, English regards the noun in a *general* sense of meaning.  For example, I might say "I like dogs" if I like dogs in general, i.e. any dog or all dogs.  If I like the specific dogs you just showed me, i.e. there is some prior context to my statement, I might say "I like the dogs."  You would understand that I was referring to those specific dogs.  It is not required, in English, that this context come in the same sentence: a preceding sentence is fine.

By the same token, the second sentence listed in the question needs context.  We need to know something about *which* differences of opinion are being addressed, and this would have been provided in the preceding sentence(s).

In the first sentence, no context is needed.  *Any* difference of opinion might be equally considered as part of the intended meaning.

Because of its ability to stand on its own, without prior context, the first sentence is more appropriate for the topic sentence of a paragraph; whereas the second sentence might be a supporting sentence.

There are many sites online that address the lack of an article when speaking of things in a general sense.  Here is [ONE EXAMPLE](https://7esl.com/use-no-article-rules/) (and probably not the best).

Comment: There is a rule that you are not mentioning that might be relevant here: In English, when we say "A of B", A becomes somewhat specific by the fact that it is "of B", and then we tend to use "the" before A. Not sure if it applies to my example.

Comment: @christianjackson  In this particular case, the noun is "differences of opinion among political parties."  Remember that nouns are defined as person, place, thing, event, or _idea_.  In this case it is the latter: an idea--after which the verb follows.

Comment: Then, by the same token, shouldn't we also avoid using "the" in "the health of democracies"?

Comment: @christianjackson As the object of the verb, and with the specification of "of democracies," the word "health" is not given in a general context; it is specific.  As a specific noun (it's not just _any_ health, but that of "democracies"), it requires the definite article.

Comment: Shouldn't the same reasoning apply to "the differences of opinion"? To me it looks like the same situation. PS: What do you think about rajesun's answer? Can you comment below it? He's unsure about it in any case. Thanks

Comment: @christianjackson Especially for those who are not native speakers of English, these finer points of grammar often present difficulties to the understanding.  I can understand why someone would have trouble--it may be that I am not explaining clearly enough.  Just the same, the article is definitely required with "health" and yet is not necessary for the subject if the subject is given in the general sense.  "I like dogs"; but "I like _the_ dogs of America." AND "Dogs (in general) are loyal"; or "the (specific) dogs are loyal."

Comment: I am still unsure about many aspects of this whole affair. For example, we all know that there are in all cases differences of opinion among political parties in all democracies. Should we then use "the" to convey the idea that there are differences in all cases (rajesun's suggestion)?

Comment: @christianjackson yes, we all know there are in all cases specific differences, but using "differences" you are pointing at all of them as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

In general I agree with [the answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/332684/91457) by rajesun.

> A. **Differences of opinion** among political parties strengthen the health of democracies.

> B. **The differences of opinion** among political parties strengthen the health of democracies.

Both (A) and (B) are correct, but their meaning is somewhat different. (A) means that differences of opinion among political parties, when and to the extent that such difference exist, make democracies healthier. (B) means that differences of opinion among political parties do in fact exist, at least at the moment when the speaker or writer is speaking or writing, and that those differences make democracies healthier.

Where I would differ from rajesun is that I do not think that (B) implies that such difference **always** exist, just that they currently do. I would also not agree that (B) implies that those differences "cannot be identified". Rather, I would say that (B) does not identify them. But I can easily imagine an essay or article in which the next sentence or paragraph went on to identify specific differences and indicate just **how** they  make democracies healthier.